# Avoid highlighting defined by 'matchadd' in comments

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want the piece of text `std::string` to be highlighted in vim according to the style defined in 'Type'. I can do that with

```
:call matchadd('Type','std::string')
```

It works. However, `std::string` is also highlighted in comments. In my code, comments follow a double slash `//`. How can I avoid highlights in comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `match()` functions are not aware of the syntax regions. So you need to fallback to change your pattern and exclude the comment pattern. Luckily for your case this is "quite easy" (well more or less) using a [negative lookbehind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

You need to use the [`/\@<!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%21), which is the negative lookbehind atom used by Vims regexp engine. That would make your pattern something like this:

```
^\s*\(\/\/.*\)\@<!std::string
```

which comes down to

```
^        - start of line
\s*      - any number of whitespace
\(       - start group
  \/\/   - Start of your Comment
  .*     - Anything
 \)      - End group
 \@<!    - negative lookbehind assertion
 std::string  - Finally the search string you actually want to have highlighted ;)
```

Comment: Why is `std::string` highlighted only when it is in the beginning of the line (excluding white spaces)? For example, `sizeof(std::string)` is not highlighted. According to your explanations, it should, right?

Comment: most likely the anchoring at the start of line prevents the match. Try whithout it

Comment: Yes, it was that. The pattern `\s*\(\/\/.*\)\@<!std::string` highlights `std::string` everywhere in non commented lines.